# Sheer Download not downloading

Tags: sheer-ui

I have implemented a custom button on the Content Editor which triggers a Custom command(which inherits from Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.Command), and when I click on the button two things happen:

1. It creates an excel file on the server which is working just fine
2. I try to download it. That's the piece that is not working.

Here is my command slightly adapted to the post:

```
protected IReportService ReportService;
        public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Warn("Report not generated. The context is null", context);
                return;
            }

            try
            {                    
                Context.ClientPage.Start(this, "GenerateReport", context.Parameters);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error("Error while generating the Excel report", ex, this);
            }
        }

        public void GenerateReport(ClientPipelineArgs args)
        {
            if (ReportService != null)
            {
                var list = ReportService.GetAssetsReport();

                var file = ExportToExcel(list);
                //The ExportToExcel returns a FileInfo object 
                Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("File name: "+ file.FullName, file);
                SheerResponse.Download(file.FullName);
            }
        }
```

If I get the value from file.FullName I see the absotule path to the file which exists on the server. If I copy this value and use it on windows explorer I see the file.
But the SheerResponse.Download will not download it.
Logs don't show any potential errors.
Any thoughts on what could be wrong?

Comment: Can you try `Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Download(file.FullName);`

Comment: Am I right saying that Sheer API doesn't work in the default configuration, as it has been replaced by SPEAK components with the new API described above?

Comment: There are a lot of components that still run on Sheer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of the problem was that the Download method was not either finding the file or having permissions to run the download.

The file itself was not being saved within the Website folder but on another folder within the server(this prevented the download from working).
I noticed that and changed the ExportToExcel method to start saving the file within a specific folder within the website folder.
After that the download started working.
I also tested Hishaam's suggestion on changing to the `Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Download(file.FullName);`

I noticed that after changing to code to store within the Website folder both:

```
Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Download(file.FullName);

SheerResponse.Download(file.FullName);
```

worked fine

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `SheerResponse.Download`, you can make use of the following code:

```
Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Download(file.FullName);
```

This is also used in the Download Package and it is meant for downloading files.

[image]

Note: I haven't tested the code. Just make sure that the file path is correct.